# Creating a grid

Tags: python-3.x, grid

I have been asked to create a grid showing `[1, ‘*’, ‘*’, ‘*’], [‘*’ , 2, ‘*’, ‘*’], [‘*’, ‘*’, 3, ‘*’]` and the final row `[‘*’, ‘*’, ‘*’, 4]`.  I was given the class see below but not for the love of it i can get the grid to print like above. i have made it all *'s but no luck, any help to get in the right direction will help.

Thanks

```
import math
def calculateDistance(loc1, loc2):
    x = (loc2[0]-loc1[0])
    y = (loc2[1]-loc1[1])
    addXY = (x*x)+(y*y)
    return math.sqrt(addXY)

testDistance = calculateDistance((1,2), (5,3))
print(testDistance)

###The implementation of the Grid ADT (Grid Class)

class Grid:

def __init__(self, n):
    self.listOfRows = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(n):
            row.append('*')
        self.listOfRows.append(row) 


def setValue (self, x, y, value):
    self.listOfRows[x - 1][y - 1] = value

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.listOfRows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just do:

```
grid = Grid(4)
grid.setValue(0,0,1)
grid.setValue(1,1,2)
grid.setValue(2,2,3)
grid.setValue(3,3,4)
```

Comment: Sorry, print statement should not be there

Comment: Is there a reason that you included `calculateDistance`? It seems kind of unrelated to the grid class, but I'm probably mistaken.

Comment: It is not required, its part of something else, so you are right

Comment: Thanks for this, once i put it in it made sense straight away, thanks again